# not contains time script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">

<span class='whocares'><div class='box'><span style='font-size:20px;color: #0BB;'>12/26/2012 is the best</span></div><br></span><span class='whocares'><div class='box'><span style='font-size:20px;color: #0BB;'>12-26-2012</span></div><br></span><span class='whocares'><div class='box'><span style='font-size:20px;color: #0BB;'>messa coockcook</span></div><br></span><script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
$(".whocares:not(:contains('" + month + "/" + day + "/"+ year+"'))").remove();
});
</script>
```

It works on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srKAT/), but not on my [server](http://dumbsearch.com/gus.php).
On my server, nothing appears when I run it.
Why is this so? What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see anything in the fiddle too.

Comment: @TanzeelKazi Really? It appears on the fiddle for me...

Comment: When I go to your page I see this`
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://www.dumbsearch.com/reminded.txt) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in <b>/home/content/76/7290476/html/remindersimportant.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />`

Comment: Sorry here's the right link: http://dumbsearch.com/gus.php

Comment: Edited the post for the right URL.

Comment: Why do you have html in your script tag? Also code in a script tag with a src wouldn't execute.

Comment: So sorry! Something so simple! It's because I forgot to close the script tag! :| Thanks @Musa for pointing it out!

Comment: @DumbProducts I couldn't see it because I am a different timezone. I changed the dates in the HTML of the fiddle and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, view your source:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://www.dumbsearch.com/reminded.txt) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in <b>/home/content/76/7290476/html/remindersimportant.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

Secondly, you need to consider for people in different timezones. For example I am in the IST timezone so here it's 27/12/2012 already.

Besides that your HTML is not well formed.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

You need a closing `</script>` here. It's one of the reasons why you can't see your error on the server.

It always helps to keep well indented code. Easy to spot such errors in crucial spots.

Comment: So sorry! Something so simple! It's because I forgot to close the script tag! :|

Comment: http://www.dumbsearch.com/reminded.txt is the wrong URL, as I editied my original post, dumbsearch.com/gus.php is the correct. Regarding the timezone, in my web app, it's done intentionally. oh, but your right, in the jsfiddle i should have changed that. thanks for doing so

Comment: @DumbProducts If it's intentional then it's okay. When posting the answer I had thought otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag for jQuery is not closed properly.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class='whocares'><div class='box'><span style='font-size:20px;color: #0BB;'>12/26/2012 is the best</span></div><br></span><span class='whocares'><div class='box'><span style='font-size:20px;color: #0BB;'>12-26-2012</span></div><br></span><span class='whocares'><div class='box'><span style='font-size:20px;color: #0BB;'>messa coockcook</span></div><br></span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
$(".whocares:not(:contains('" + month + "/" + day + "/"+ year+"'))").remove();
});
</script>
```